# cross-env is not recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, node-modules

Problem performing npm run prod. The first thing that appeared to me when I executed this command is:

```
cross-env is not recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file
```

So I did this

```
npm install -g cross-env
```

And now when I run npm run prod I get this message:

```
The system can not find the path specified.
node:events:489
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)  
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)  
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)       
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)       
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--no-progress',
    '--hide-modules',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.3.0
```

Tell them that I do not have the node_modules folder in the project, because when trying npm i, this appears:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: laravel-mix-purgecss@6.0.0
npm ERR! Found: laravel-mix@4.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!   dev laravel-mix@"^4.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer laravel-mix@"^6.0.0" from laravel-mix-purgecss@6.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/laravel-mix-purgecss
npm ERR!   dev laravel-mix-purgecss@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: laravel-mix@6.0.49
npm ERR! node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!   peer laravel-mix@"^6.0.0" from laravel-mix-purgecss@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/laravel-mix-purgecss
npm ERR!     dev laravel-mix-purgecss@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-13T16_04_19_341Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-13T16_04_19_341Z-debug-0.log
```

I am trying to build a project that is not mine and well I have this problem to run npm run prod and make the project work, to see if you could help me

How to run npm run prod